# How many times Android was picked up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app that keeps track of how many times the user uses their phone, meaning how many times they picked up/checked their phone everyday. I've searched through stackoverflow and other sites but I can't find any information that would help me implement this; any ideas? Is there a certain class I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BroadcastService and IntentFilter to keep track of when the screen is turned on and off (ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF). Each time the screen is turned on, increase a counter.

Answer (score 0):

You could register for the ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcast.  Then just increment a counter (saved to disk just in case) each time its received.  But you can't do that via the manifest, so you'd need to do it in a foreground service.

Comment: What do you mean by do it in a foreground service?

Comment: I mean you need to register the broadcast receiver in a foreground service.  Newer versions of Android do not allow you to register for that broadcast in your manifest.